# epoll does not signal an event when socket is close

Tags: c++, c, linux, epoll

I have a listener socket, every new connection I get I add it to epoll like this:

```
int connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clnt_addr, &clnt_addr_len);
ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT | EPOLLHUP;
ev.data.fd = connfd;
epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connfd, &ev)
```

When new data is received, epoll signal 'EPOLLIN' event - as expected.

In such a situation I read all the information as follows:

```
long read = 0;
do {
    read = recv(events[n].data.fd, buffer, sizeof (buffer), 0);
} while (read > 0);
```

In case I disconnected brutally or normally, epoll does not signal an event.

This code run in each thread, that's what I'm using EPOLLET.

So my question:

1. What do I need to do to get this event?
2. What do I need to do to close the socket so that there is no leakage of resources?

Comment: Why are you using `EPOLLONESHOT`? This flag disables further events, if you already got one.

Comment: [RTM](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html): "When the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag is
       specified, it is the caller's responsibility to rearm the file
       descriptor using `epoll_ctl` with `EPOLL_CTL_MOD`."  If you don't read the manual pages for functions you really shouldn't be writing C code that uses them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your attempt.

1. You should not use `EPOLLONESHOT` unless you know what you are doing and you really need it. It disables the report of any other events to the epoll instance until you enable it again with `EPOLL_CTL_MOD`.
2. You should not use `EPOLLHUP` to determine if a connection was closed. The `EPOLLHUP` event may be raised before all data is read from the socket input stream, even if the client disconnects gracefully. I recommend you to only use `EPOLLIN`. If there is no input left (because of forceful or graceful disconnect), the `read()` would return `0` (EOF) and you can close the socket.
3. Your `read()` call will block the reading thread and consume the whole stream until EOF (connection closed). The whole point in using `epoll()` is to not have to use a `while ( read(...) > 0 )` loop.
4. You should not use `EPOLLET` because "the code runs multithreaded" but because you need it. You can write multithreaded code without the edge-triggered mode. The use of `EPOLLET` requires a thorough knowledge of the differences between blocking and non-blocking I/O. You can easily run into pitfalls (as mentioned in the manual), like edge-triggered starvation.